# unable to access object in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to access object key. The key is shown in object in console but when I am trying to access that key its return `undefined`. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EGNSw/117/)

```
console.log(e) //object
console.log(e.data.$menu) // undefined
console.log(e.data.selector) // .context-menu-one
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm confused: in your third line, did you mean `console.log(e.data)` ? You have `console.log(e.data.$menu)` twice with two different outputs.

Comment: Is your issue on IE ? from your fiddle: `// NOTE: this is the item that wraps in IE9 but not in Firefox`

Comment: @naomik: Sorry that was my typo error, I have edit my question

Comment: If it yields `undefined` *when* accessed, then that means it's `undefined` *at that time*. Where is `.$menu` populated?

Comment: @CrayonViolent: it is still showing undefined

Comment: @Bergi: i have printed whole object in console. $menu is showing up there and when I print 'selector' which is also part of that object is print successfully on console

Comment: @amit: Please read the linked question I've closed yours as a duplicate of. Why the property is *not yet* populated when you log the object, we only can tell with insight in your code - please post it.

Comment: @Bergi: I have attached fiddle

Comment: @amit: Sorry I didn't notice, but the relevant code should go into the question anyway (please edit it in). And that fiddle you linked (http://stackoverflow.com/q/24662289/1048572) doesn't even contain the log statements you claim are not working? Did you paste the correct link? Or what do I need to do in that fiddle to reproduce your issue?

Comment: @Bergi: I have updated the correct link

Comment: @amit: OK, after I've fixed the syntax error in there I can confirm that the `build` callback is called *before* the menu element is created and assigned to that `.$menu` property. (See the duplicate for why it still shows up in the console). So what? Why did you expect to be able to access it, do the docs of that plugin mention it somewhere? What is your actual question?